# Link to entire table cells with text and image

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble to have link in image and in text in the same cell. Text in cells should be at center and aligned to right or left (**see picture**).

[image]

Here is what I have now http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/787/:

```html
<table>
   <tr>
   <td >      
     <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">TEXT HERE
     <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" alt="description here" />
     </a>
   </td>
     <td>
       <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">TEXT HERE
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" alt="description here" />
       </a>
     </td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td >      
     <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">TEXT HERE
     <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" alt="description here" />
     </a>
   </td>
     <td>
       <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">TEXT HERE
         <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" alt="description here" />
       </a>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I have also tried to accomplish this by using image as backgound-image in cells, but then I was able to have link only in text, not also in image. Example:

```html
<table>
   <tr>
     <td width="100px" height="100px" BACKGROUND="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" VALIGN="center"  >
       <a href="/http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">TEXT 
       </a>
     </td>
     <td width="100px" height="100px" BACKGROUND="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" VALIGN="center"  >
       
       <a href="/http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">TEXT 
       </a>
     </td>

   </tr>
      <tr>

     <td width="100px" height="100px" BACKGROUND="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" VALIGN="center"  >
       
       <a href="/http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">TEXT 
       </a>
     </td>
     <td width="100px" height="100px" BACKGROUND="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" VALIGN="center"  >
       
       <a href="/http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">TEXT 
       </a>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use background-image instead iamge

Comment: @לבנימלכה See my edit with second example where I have used backgroud-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use position `CSS` to achieve this. Check the following edits, where I have wrapped your text inside a `<span>` with some css.

```css
td a{
  display:block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  line-height:1px;
}
span.text-link-left{
    position: absolute;
    color: #002945;
    display:block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 8%;
} 
    span.text-link-right{
    position: absolute;
    color: #002945;
    display:block;
    top: 50%;
    right: 8%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
   <td >      
     <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">
        <span class="text-link-left">TEXT HERE</span>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" alt="description here" />
     </a>
   </td>
     <td>
       <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">
          <span class="text-link-right">TEXT HERE</span>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" alt="description here" />
       </a>
     </td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td >      
     <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">
        <span class="text-link-left">TEXT HERE</span>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" alt="description here" />
     </a>
   </td>
     <td>
       <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">
          <span class="text-link-right">TEXT HERE</span>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" alt="description here" />
       </a>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This seems to be working as it should! How can I align texts to those positions which are shown in my question picture? They should be aligned to center-right or center-left.

Answer (score 0):

You can used css like this

```
td:nth-child(2n){text-align:right;}
```

or

```
td:nth-child(2n) a{float:right;}
```

you can check in https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_nth-child.asp

```css
td:nth-child(2n){
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
     <td width="100px" height="100px" BACKGROUND="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" VALIGN="center"  >
       <a href="/http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">TEXT 
       </a>
     </td>
     <td width="100px" height="100px" BACKGROUND="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" VALIGN="center"  >
       
       <a href="/http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">TEXT 
       </a>
     </td>

   </tr>
      <tr>

     <td width="100px" height="100px" BACKGROUND="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" VALIGN="center"  >
       
       <a href="/http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">TEXT 
       </a>
     </td>
     <td width="100px" height="100px" BACKGROUND="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" VALIGN="center"  >
       
       <a href="/http://jsfiddle.net/7aHDR/783/">TEXT 
       </a>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Pictures should have links also, see @kravisingh's right answer.